# Envelope custom fields on email resource file

Tags: docusignapi

I have created a custom field at the envelope level  example :

```
List<TextCustomField> textCustomFields = new ArrayList<TextCustomField>();
TextCustomField tcfEnvelopeName = new TextCustomField();
tcfEnvelopeName.setName("EMPLOYEE_NUMBER");
tcfEnvelopeName.setValue(firstEnvName);``
textCustomFields.add(tcfEnvelopeName);
```

And on the email resource file  I have mentioned [[Data: EMPLOYEE_NUMBER]] then its's showing as  [[Data: EMPLOYEE_NUMBER]] instead of the EmployeeNumber.  Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`Envelope Custom fields` is not available on the `email resource` file.

Comment: DO you know any other way to add the custom fields to the emailresource file?

Comment: Can you please share what are you trying to achieve in the email? Something in email body or email subject?

Comment: We are trying to cover a scenario when a manager(signer 1) receives envelopes for multiple associates(singer 2,3.....) he should be able to identify by seeing the email itself for whom this envelope is associated with. For this reason we want to know a way to mention all the signers on the email body. Note: SInger don't have docusign accounts

Comment: So when you are sending email to signer1 your code knows who is signer2,3 (multiple associates)? If yes, then you can use “emailnotification” property inside signer or “node” property inside signer. Using these you can send explicit message to the manager which will be visible to manager only.

Comment: Thank you Amit, can we change the "Personal Note:" label that appears in the email body that appears while using notes?.  I looked at the DocuSign_SignResourcesMaster.xml,DocuSign_SendResourcesMaster.xml, they doesn't seem to be having a label for "Personal NOte"

Comment: Do you mean "Private Message" which appears on the email body? and what you want to change it to?

Comment: Personal Note:
This is for Pratheek                    :: It appears like this in the email body when I set note to "This is for Pratheek". Can I change "Personal Note": label?

Comment: The label is present in the `email resource file` and by default DocuSign gives label as "PRIVATE MESSAGE", since you are seeing "Personal Note", it means someone in your account has changed to to "Personal Note" in the Brand's email resource file.

Comment: Thank you again Amilt, coiming to  emailNotification in Signer.java seems to be setting entire email body for signer instead of using emailresource.xml. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: emailresource.xml is the template which will load the data from the emailNotification. Static data is added in the emailresource.xml, dynamic data is used in the emailbody either thru emailNotification or using emailBlurb.

Comment: I see using [[:EmailBlurb]] we can add the emailBlurb content to the emailresource.xml. HOw can we add the emailNotification emailbody to the emailresource.xml?. Is there any specific tag for it to be placed on the emailresource.xml

Comment: If you have not altered anything in [[Data:EmailBlurb]], then emailNotification's emailbody will automatically come in the email. You do not need to place anything in emailresource.xml. [[Data:RecipientNote]] is required for the private note or private message.

Comment: My emailresource.xml is completely customized, not sure what do you mean by not altering [[Data:EmailBlurb]]. I did not altered EmailBlurb through the API. I have tried setting the email body through api, but it did not show up in the email body.  I believe it requires some tag in the emailresource.xml file

Comment: The default emailresource file provided by DocuSign Branding always has [[Data:EmailBlurb]] and if this is present then it will automatically renders the emailbody. If its not present then you need to check if someone has deleted it from your email resource file. Also you need to know which `data` node you are changing in the resource file, normally a signer uses `EnvelopeActivation_HtmlBody` data node in the email resource file. Check [Email Resource File](https://www.docusign.com/supportdocs/pdf/docusign-email-resource-file(v1.1).pdf) for more details.

Comment: Thank you for the response it solved my problem, When  we set the EmailBlurb message it's also appearing on the screen where we check electronic disclosure, can we avoid this appearing on the screen?

Comment: EmailBlurb should not appear on the signing screen, it is PrivateMessage/Private Note which would appear on the signing screen. Can you mark this qs as resolved and open a new qs with the issue's screenshot and the API call where your are setting the email body.

Answer (score 0):

Amit K Bist did a great job in answering all my questions
1)We can not refer custom fields of an envelope directly into an emailresource.xml
2)We can over come this by using [[EmailBlurb]] on the emailresource.xml and setting emailNotification (need to set emailBody field) field in the signer.java
3)How ever this emailBlurb is appearing on the docusign welcome page where electroinicDisclosure is checked(It might be only for me because of some settings)